# How to sell a Pregnant Kosher Bechor Animal to a Non Jew to avoid a Bechor

Tags: bechor-firstborn

what is the correct way for it to be sold? do you need a shtar, (assuming the animal cannot be picked up). or is kinyan kessef enough? like if the non Jew pays you $2.00 cash are you fully covered?

Comment: A local vet told me that his rov told him that kinyan kesef is enough for sirus, but the money paid must be a reasonable amount of money for that animal, so it is not domeh le'chuka u'telulah. I.e. it does not have to be the full price, but it does need to be a significant sum of money.

Answer (score 1):

Heard on a yutorah shiur (I think R Sobolofsky?) that we do the same combination of mechanisms as with selling chametz. Cash, handshake, real estate, you name it. (I heard a story of a fellow in Baltimore who owned some ewes and kept them on some farmland that didn't belong to him. As he had to sell part of them to a non-Jew via land he owned, he brought them onto his yard, a couple blocks away from the Agudah shul, and Rabbi Heinemann shlit'a presided over the sale.)

Comment: R' Sobolofsky is certainly the expert on Bekhorot, but here it's a bit more complicated than selling chametz because there are more possibly relevant kinyanim (like leading it on a leash and locking it in a pen). No one should be attempting this themselves based on the internet.